# How to handle insufficient information about the collected data in the dataset?

Tags: dataset, data, data-cleaning

I am trying to create a ML model to predict foodborne diseases. I found online a few datasets with the informations I need. The problem is that **none of them explains how** they got the medical measures.

For the diabetes, for example, I need to know in which condition they got the measures of glucose. Due to the lack of these information, I'm afraid my model may be unreliable. How can I deal with that? Which strategy do you suggest?

Comment: one approach would be to deal with ranges instead of fixed values, so error is minimised at the expense of more generality

Comment: Did you find the papers introducing the datasets? Normally this is where this kind of information is explained in detail.

Comment: Yes I did but the measures were not specified